# html5 sending an email with speciel charactes doesnt work in chrome from Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm sending an email as following:

```
<a href="rhomailto:test@host.com?cc=geny@mail.ru&bcc=vasy@gmail.com&body="+strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars + &subject=sub1">Send e-mail to test@host.com</a>
```

I want that the email body will contain multiple lines.
Im trying to send the body string as following:

1. `strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars = "hello" + "%0A" + "I like this."; but in the mail body the string displayed as:"hello" + "%0A" + "I like this."`
2. strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars = strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars.encodeURIComponent(strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars);

the string displayed as:"hello" + "%0A" + "I like this."

3. `strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars = strValidStringWithHandlingSpechielChars.Replace("\n", "%0A");`
   the string displayed as:"hello" + "%0A" + "I like this."

In chrome using android devices its not working as showing above, unlike using with safari, in safari each of the lines above works and we get the sentence in 2 separate lines...

I need a generic solution for all these kind of chars like !@#$<>%
How can i solve it in android too?

Comment: try to use String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); instead of "%0A"

Comment: I need a generic solution for all these kind of chars like !@#$<>%